# XElement.ToString() causes System.OutOfMemoryException

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, memory

I have an `XElement` object that contains about 120MB of data. The XML consists of approx 6000 elements of about 20kb each.

I am trying to call `XElement.ToString()` as I need to return the OuterXml in a webservice.

I am getting a `System.OutOfMemoryException`.

```
System.OutOfMemoryException: Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.
   at System.String.GetStringForStringBuilder(String value, Int32 startIndex, Int32 length, Int32 capacity)
   at System.Text.StringBuilder.GetNewString(String currentString, Int32 requiredLength)
   at System.Text.StringBuilder.Append(Char[] value, Int32 startIndex, Int32 charCount)
   at System.IO.StringWriter.Write(Char[] buffer, Int32 index, Int32 count)
   at System.Xml.XmlEncodedRawTextWriter.FlushBuffer()
   at System.Xml.XmlEncodedRawTextWriter.WriteAttributeTextBlock(Char* pSrc, Char* pSrcEnd)
   at System.Xml.XmlEncodedRawTextWriter.WriteString(String text)
   at System.Xml.XmlEncodedRawTextWriterIndent.WriteString(String text)
   at System.Xml.XmlWellFormedWriter.WriteString(String text)
   at System.Xml.XmlWriter.WriteAttributeString(String prefix, String localName, String ns, String value)
   at System.Xml.Linq.ElementWriter.WriteStartElement(XElement e)
   at System.Xml.Linq.ElementWriter.WriteElement(XElement e)
   at System.Xml.Linq.XElement.WriteTo(XmlWriter writer)
   at System.Xml.Linq.XNode.GetXmlString(SaveOptions o)
   at System.Xml.Linq.XNode.ToString()
```

I have the same data in an `XmlDocument` and can call `XmlDocument.OuterXml` without a problem. I can also call `XElement.Save()` to save the XML to a file without a problem.

Can anyone suggest an alternative to XElement.ToString() that would be less memory intensive? Or alternatively some parameters I can set that would allow for a larger memory space?

Comment: You need to return 120mb of data over a web service...

Comment: that's what I was thinking...

Comment: try to compact the data and return it

Comment: It's an internal web service that is just used to transfer the data between two separate internal systems. Generally either on the same server or at worst side by side in a rack.

Comment: If it's for internal systems I still wouldn't use a web service for that. If theres any sort of load on the network then the request is going to be kept open far too long. Why can't you FTP it around the network or shove it on a shared directory somewhere? Or something OTHER than a HTTP request.

Comment: Apart from this one case, the data is generally around 1MB. At this time I am not able to change the second system. Either way, the problem I have is not with the web service. All of that is working fine. It is purely the XElement.ToString() that I am having a problem with.

Comment: Sending 1MB files around using a web service is fine, my issue is your trying to send 120MB file around :( I think you would need to either compress the result or stream it.

Comment: At this time I am not able to change the second system.

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like you're writing *way* too much data there; *generally* raw `XmlWriter` might be the best option for this volume. However, if you can `Save()` successfully you could perhaps try:

```
    string xml;
    using(var sw = new StringWriter()) {
        el.Save(sw);
        xml = sw.ToString();
    }
```

or maybe:

```
    string xml;
    using (var ms = new MemoryStream()) { 
        using(var tw = new StreamWriter(ms, Encoding.UTF8))
        {
            el.Save(tw);            
        }
        xml = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ms.GetBuffer(), 0, (int)ms.Length);
    }
```

But either (or both) of these might still explode in a shower of sparks. You might also want to investigate [`XStreamingElement`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xstreamingelement.aspx) which is designed for this type of scenario... but still, that is a lot of xml - **especially** for a web-service. Would you be open to suggestions of alternative (much denser) serializiation formats?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.

Set the WCF service's `transferMode` to `Streamed` or `StreamedResponse`. Also enable compression on the web server to cut the download size down to about 10% of the size.

Comment: I have no problem with the web service. The problem is purely in getting the XMLin an XElement into a string variable.

Comment: @Robin Day: If you investigate further, you will see you have exhausted memory available to the web server. I started seeing the same issue when my responses got to around 120MB. How much memory you have on that server? Mine was 4GB, I am not however sure adding more memory will help.